# Ubuntu 9.10 x86_32 with PAE causes graphics issues, mainly slowness

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, nvidia-graphics-card, pae

I've tried the 64bit version and found I was constantly hitting a brick wall trying to get 32bit stuff to run; I'd previously used PAE on 9.04 without any issues so figured I'd give it a shot.

However, on 9.10 it seems PAE or the process of enabling PAE breaks the nvidia drivers/module somewhat as performance is terrible; I can't even enable desktop effects and there's lots of artifacting on random controls.

Disabling the pae image and rebooting fixes the issue however I'm then stuck with "only" 2.7Gb of ram and unable to use the full 8gb that's installed.

Is there somthing special I need to do when using pae and nVidia drivers or should I be using 64bit and just figure out how to force run 32bit packages? :-p

Comment: ...heh.  nVidia should be one of the tags on this.

Comment: [PAE really really sucks](https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/) - said Linus Torvalds. It's not a good solution http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_32_pae&num=1

Answer (score 1):

A [comment](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-4gb-ram-limitation-solution/#comment-39631) on a [PAE how-to post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-4gb-ram-limitation-solution/) indicates you need to *disable* the restricted driver, *then* install the PAE-enabled kernel, reboot, *then* re-enable the restricted driver.  This was from pre-9.04 but sounds like general PAE advice.  Is this the procedure you used when installing your PAE kernel?

Comment: No. I did notice that when enabling/disabling pae depmod(?) rebuilds the modules... I'll see if the reboots in between work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that enabling PAE is limiting your available memory?  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-4gb-ram-limitation-solution/ seems to indicate the reverse...

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/slackware-linux-help/145583-kernel-support-pae-post692103.html#post692103

Comment: PAE works fine; It just breaks the nVidia driver.